# remove duplicates in powershell when there are two parameters

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I have a data as follows :

```
           Percent         SiteName      
-------------------------- --------      
                     95.15 Walnu  
                     88.15 Tucson        
                     99.14 Tarrace       
                     99.39 Tampa         
                     94.73 walnu 
                     92.85 Tarrace
```

I want to remove the duplicates in sitename and want the data as :

```
              Percent         SiteName      
    -------------------------- --------      
                         95.15 Walnu  
                         88.15 Tucson        
                         99.14 Tarrace       
                         99.39 Tampa
```

select-object -unique works only when i want a single parameter in the output. Is there any method to do this.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you actually put sample data I can copy and paste, I could help. I’m not willing to type up what you already have as text somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter out *extra* objects that contain an already output `SiteName` value, you can use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7).

```
# $data contains your collection of objects
$data | Group-Object SiteName | Foreach-Object { $_.Group[0] }
```

`Group-Object` creates a collection of items based on property values. Using `SiteName` will retrieve all duplicate `SiteName` valued objects into a `GroupInfo` object. The `Group` property contains the collection of all grouped objects. Using the index `[0]`, the first one will be output, which works even for `SiteName` values that have no duplicates.